# OS displays on both mobo and graphics card regardless of IGD/PEG, but BIOS doesn't display on PEG?

Tags: boot, graphics-card, bios, motherboard

Accessing my computer's BIOS is a complete pain. When one or more of my monitors are connected to my graphics card display port, the BIOS screen loads but is blank. I've narrowed down the problem with some confidence to the mobo's setting "Initiative Graphics Adapter." What port my monitors are plugged in, and what setting this is, yields the following, replicable results:

- When in IGD, connected to graphics card: BIOS is blank, OS displays
- When in IGD, connected to mobo: BIOS works, OS displays *(This is great, but it uses the integrated graphics and not the GPU)*
- When in PEG, connected to the graphics card: BIOS is blank, OS displays
- When in PEG, connected to the mobo: BIOS is blank, OS displays

> The only way I can get back to the BIOS after switching to PEG is removing the graphics card.

Having the Initiative Graphics Adapter setting set to PEG is clearly less convenient, as if I want access to the BIOS I have to remove my graphics card every time. What I'm doing now is setting it to IGD, moving the cable to the mobo port if I need access to the BIOS, then back to the graphics card when I'm done.

Why is this happening? Is there a way to boot from the BIOS (scenario #2, but connected to the graphics card) from the graphics card port?

#### My system

- MSI Z490-A Pro
- Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080
- BIOS mode is UEFI
- OS is Windows 10

#### Things I've tried and narrowed down

- "Fast boot" is off
- Resetting CMOS has no effect
- "Multi-monitor" IGD has no effect
- Whether I have one or both my monitors plugged in, does not matter (I've tried every combo; there's no apparent difference)
- When the BIOS screen is blank, the mobo brand screen does not load. The brand screen and the ability to view the BIOS screen seemingly is directly related.
- When the graphics card is removed, both PEG and IGD display both BIOS and OS.
- Reading the Z490-A Pro manual provides no obvious answers (subjective of course; I'm just saying I read the manual).
- In PEG mode, pressing Shift + Click on Restart to "restart in UEFI mode to adjust firmware," which I'm assuming is Windows' fancy way of going to the BIOS screen, does not display.

Comment: Most BIOS/UEFI cannot use a graphic card, only the integrated display.

Comment: Yea, this is a tale as old as time with HDMI ...*Beauty and the Beast music*... You might have luck trying DisplayPort or DVI instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact same issue. I resolved with this Diplayport firmware update tool from nvidia

https://www.nvidia.com/content/DriverDownloads/confirmation.php?url=/Windows/uefi/firmware/1.1/NVIDIA_DisplayID_Firmware_Updater_1.1-x64.exe&firmware=1&lang=us&type=Other

Comment: Normally link only answers are not okay.  But in this case, it is fine.

Comment: I upgraded to Windows 11, but the problem still persisted. However, with the update to Windows 11, I had a new firmware and/or driver update (I don't remember). After that update, the monitors started working as expected. Who knows what was wrong, but the update fixed it‍♂️ Thanks for the time to answer